# What's a good way to combine two custom filters I made into one custom filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've made two custom filters that are very similar. The only thing that's different between these two filters is the array that is being used. I thus want to make one custom filter and give it an array as a parameter. The arrays I'd then pass into the function would be $rootScope.selectedCategories and $rootScope.selectedBrands. Now my problem is that I don't know where to declare a variable that I can give as argument to the filter, as seen below.

```
<div class="productContentBox" ng-repeat="top in store.tops | categoryFilter: argument1 | orderBy: propertyName">
```

I've already tried to create a scope variable in my controller which looked like the code below. And then use 'categoryArray' as argument for my categoryFilter (so replace 'argument1' with 'categoryArray' in the code above). However this didn't work out, I think the reason therefore is because I think it doesn't get updated with the current $rootScope.selectedCategories (this array is not static and can be changed based on checkboxes).

```
$scope.categoryArray = $rootScope.selectedCategories;
```

Here is the code for the first filter:

```
  // Filter that filters on the products' category.
  app.filter('categoryFilter', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return function(items) {
      // Show all products if all filters are deselected.
      if ($rootScope.selectedCategories.length == 0 || checkOnlyFalse($rootScope.selectedCategories))  {
        return items;
      }
      else {
        var filtered = [];
        for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
          var item = items[i];
          // Push the products that match the filter criteria on the array.
          for (var j=0; j < $rootScope.selectedCategories.length; j++)
          if (item.category == $rootScope.selectedCategories[j]){
            filtered.push(item);
          }
        }
        return filtered;
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Here is the code for the second filter:

```
  // Filter that filters on the products' brand.
  app.filter('brandFilter', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return function(items) {
      // Show all products if all filters are deselected.
      if ($rootScope.selectedBrands.length == 0 || checkOnlyFalse($rootScope.selectedBrands))  {
        return items;
      }
      else {
        var filtered = [];
        for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
          var item = items[i];
          // Push the products that match the filter criteria on the array.
          for (var j=0; j < $rootScope.selectedBrands.length; j++)
          if (item.brand == $rootScope.selectedBrands[j]){
            filtered.push(item);
          }
        }
        return filtered;
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution

```
app.filter('productFilter', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  return function(items,filterOn) {
    var filtered = [];
    // Show all products if all filters are deselected.
    if('categories'===filterOn) {
      if ($rootScope.selectedCategories.length == 0 || checkOnlyFalse($rootScope.selectedCategories))  {
      filtered=items;
      } else {
        for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
          var item = items[i];
          // Push the products that match the filter criteria on the array.
          for (var j=0; j < $rootScope.selectedCategories.length; j++) {
            if (item.category == $rootScope.selectedCategories[j]){
              filtered.push(item);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } else if('brands'===filterOn) {
    // Show all products if all filters are deselected.
        if ($rootScope.selectedBrands.length == 0 || checkOnlyFalse($rootScope.selectedBrands))  {
          filtered=items;
        } else {
          var filtered = [];
          for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
            // Push the products that match the filter criteria on the array.
            for (var j=0; j < $rootScope.selectedBrands.length; j++)  {
              if (item.brand == $rootScope.selectedBrands[j]){
              filtered.push(item);
              }
            }
          }
        }
     }
     return filtered;
   };
}]);
```

This can be used in your html as

```
<div class="productContentBox" ng-repeat="top in (store.tops | product: 'categories') | orderBy: category">
```